# How to measure time spent in blocking code while using asyncio in Python?

Tags: python, performance, asynchronous, python-asyncio, metrics

I'm currently migrating some Python code that used to be blocking to use `asyncio` with `async/await`. It is a lot of code to migrate at once so I would prefer to do it gradually and have metrics. With that thing in mind I want to create a decorator to wrap some functions and know how long they are blocking the event loop. For example:

```py
def measure_blocking_code(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # ?????
        # It should measure JUST 1 second
        # not 5 which is what the whole async function takes
    return wrapper

@measure_blocking_code
async def my_function():
    my_blocking_function()  # Takes 1 seconds
    await my_async_function()  # Takes 2 seconds
    await my_async_function_2()  # Takes 2 seconds
```

I know the event loop has a debug function that already report this, but I need to get that information for specific functions.

Comment: If you decorate my_function, and my_function ACTUALLY takes 5 seconds to execute, how do you expect Python to know that you really want to measure the time duration of one of its internal steps?  Shouldn't you be decorating my_blocking_function instead?

Comment: @PaulCornelius Python yields the control when you call await. 4 of those 5 seconds are spent in the event loop, not in my code. The reason I need to decorate my_function is because I don't exactly know which calls are blocking. In this example is really easy to see, but in a big codebase is harder, also I need the aggregate, not each function individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TLDR;

This decorator does the job:

```py
def measure_blocking_code(f):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t = 0
        coro = f()
        try:
            while True:
                t0 = time.perf_counter()
                future = coro.send(None)
                t1 = time.perf_counter()
                t += t1 - t0
                while not future.done():
                    await asyncio.sleep(0)
                future.result()  # raises exceptions if any
        except StopIteration as e:
            print(f'Function took {t:.2e} sec')
            return e.value
    return wrapper
```

## Explanation

This workaround exploits the conventions used in `asyncio` implementation in cPython. These conventions are a superset of PEP-492. In other words:

1. You can generally use async/await without knowing these details.
2. This might not work with other async libraries like *trio*.

An `asyncio` coro object (`coro`) can be executed by calling `.send()` member. This will only run the blocking code, until an async call yields a Future object. By only measuring the time spent in `.send()`, the duration of the blocking code can be determined.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way. I hope it helps somebody

```py
import asyncio
import time


def measure(f):    
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        coro_wrapper = f(*args, **kwargs).__await__()
        fut = asyncio.Future()

        total_time = 0
        def done(arg=None):
            try:
                nonlocal total_time
                start_time = time.perf_counter()
                next_fut = coro_wrapper.send(arg)
                end_time = time.perf_counter()
                total_time += end_time - start_time
                next_fut.add_done_callback(done)
            except StopIteration:
                fut.set_result(arg)
            except Exception as e:
                fut.set_exception(e)

        done()
        res = await fut
        print('Blocked for: ' + str(total_time) + ' seconds')
        return res

    return wrapper
```